# awk loop to retrieve substr does not work

Tags: loops, awk, substr

I am trying to get a variable from a file "cnt.txt" , that keeps changing, and to write a line to another file , precisely when file 1 changes. But it doesn't work. :(

```
    #!/bin/bash
    PATH="/sbin:/bin"

    for (( ; ; ))
    do

    #line to be read
    #1514001 78O8jSdxCl7 1.00 24.00 23.00

    Ser=$(awk '/1514001/ { print substr($0,1,200) }' /cnt.txt)

    #Should get ' 78' but it gets '151' ??
    Num=$(awk '/1514001/ { print substr($0,8,3) }' /cnt.txt)

    if [ $Comp != $Num ]; then
       Comp = Num
       echo $Ser   >> output.txt
    fi
    done
```

Example lines (altough are several lines here, the line actually gets updated in the same position, what varies is the number in the 8th position, (78,79,80..)

```
1514001 78gcntCUZlX7FPZOwOr3fUY+knNddOCJscqWG6HauHn7vS0dWP4yBM3kyPI4HmUIWNI2QzlaGe9S
1514001 78gcntCUZlX7FPZOwOr3fUY+knNddOCJscqWG6HauHn7vS0dWP4yBM3kyPI4HmUIWNI2QzlaGe9S
1514001 78gcntCUZlX7FPZOwOr3fUY+knNddOCJscqWG6HauHn7vS0dWP4yBM3kyPI4HmUIWNI2QzlaGe9S
1514001 79gcntCUZlX7FPZOwOr3fUY+knNddOCJscqWG6HauHn7vS0dWP4yBM3kyPI4HmUIWNI2QzlaGe9S
1514001 79gcntCUZlX7FPZOwOr3fUY+knNddOCJscqWG6HauHn7vS0dWP4yBM3kyPI4HmUIWNI2QzlaGe9S
1514001 79gcntCUZlX7FPZOwOr3fUY+knNddOCJscqWG6HauHn7vS0dWP4yBM3kyPI4HmUIWNI2QzlaGe9S
1514001 79gcntCUZlX7FPZOwOr3fUY+knNddOCJscqWG6HauHn7vS0dWP4yBM3kyPI4HmUIWNI2QzlaGe9S
1514001 80gcntCUZlX7FPZOwOr3fUY+knNddOCJscqWG6HauHn7vS0dWP4yBM3kyPI4HmUIWNI2QzlaGe9S
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to make this work with `tail`?

```
tail -f /cnt.txt | awk '/1514001/ { print substr($0,1,200) }' >> output.txt
```

It will read the file `cnt.txt` and every time it change, it sends data to `awk` that process it and sends data to `output.txt`

Comment: the lines in the file are not always in the some position, they are created in the end of the file, but then they are updated in the some position and other values get appended to cnt.tct, values that I dont want

Comment: If you post example lines, we may be able to make a filter to get the correct data

Answer (score 0):

Rather than parse the file twice, which might be affected by ongoing changes, can you echo the Ser variable into the second awk statement.

```
Num=$(echo $Ser | awk '/1514001/ { print substr($0,8,3) }')
```

Comment: It works, but the comparison doesn't. I always get the line printed, even if Num doesn't change

Comment: I think you need to change to: Comp = $Num